# Mod rewrite and redirect solution

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

we have hundreds of locations and build a separate Page for each in `wordpress` (location-in-some-state...):  `ourdomian.com/location-in-some-state/`
Works great.

SEO guys want another page with different design for seo:  `ourdomain.com/newpage/location-in-some-state`
We don't want to change the template because we still use the old one.
I am going to build a new page and pull the data with the slug:

```
 'categories'=> 'location-in-some-state',
```

So I need to redirect `ourdomain.com/location-in-some-state to ourdomain.com/newpage/`

Something like this but I think there's a infinite loop here

```
  RewriteRule ^newpage/(.*)$ /newpage/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Lastly,  I need the 'location-in-some-state' for my slug somehow.  Can that be moved to a query string or visible in the url but now rewritten?  If it can be redirected to `/newpage/`  and rewritten (visual only) with `/newpage/location-in-some-state`, maybe I can pull it out of the URI, or can the URI be sent to a query string?????

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^newpage/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newpage/$1 [L,R=301]
```